# How to load firebase storage image to fresco without losing cache functionality?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, fresco

This is how I am downloading the image url

```
StorageReference gsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

gsReference.child(<image_path>).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // use fresco to load images
    }
});
```

An then I use Fresco like this:

```
StorageReference gsReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

gsReference.child(<image_path>).getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        ImageRequest request1 = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(Uri.parse(uri))
                .setProgressiveRenderingEnabled(true)
                .build();
        DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setImageRequest(request1)
                .setControllerListener(this)
                .setOldController(imageView.getController())
                .build();

        imageView.setController(controller);
    }
});
```

When the user is offline, I lose Fresco caching functionality because I have to download the image url to use in fresco. So the image url never loads.

How can I fetch the image from fresco's cache, so I can load images even offline and can't retrieve the download url?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If the user is offline, what do you still expect to work from this code that doesn't work?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When the user is offline, I would still like to fetch the image stored in Fresco´s cache.

Comment: Thanks! And what part about the code you shared is not working towards that right now?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen every thing in the code works. I just don't know how I would be able to fetch the cached image in Fresco without internet connection since the image url is fetched from firebase storage api. and to fetch the cahced image, we need to pass the image uri to Fresco api.

Answer (score 0):

Determining the download URL for an image at a path requires a connection to the Google servers. There is no way to call `getDownloadURL()` while your device is offline.

But since the download URL is purely based on your `<image_path>` you can maintain a local map of `<image_path>` to download URLs and use that when the device is offline. Then with the resulting download URL you can load the image from the cache.

In fact, most apps I know store the download URL in one of Firebase's databases (Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore). Since both of those continue to serve data while they are offline, those apps *can* already can continue use the download URL while offline.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Maintaining my own downloadURL registry is a big task for my use case.  Have you explored the use of Glide to fetch firebase storage images?  Firebase documentation recommends this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui

Comment: The problem here is not in caching the image data itself, but in your needing to get the download URL from the server. If you don't maintain your own list of download URLs, the only way to get it is to call the server. Since you don't want to do that either, you'll have to choose: either your app won't work while you're offline, or you'll have to write some code to store/cache the download URL.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `getDownloadUrl`, that's another useless call counting to latency. After all, you don't need publicly accessible URL, when you can call Firebase functions directly.

Rather create your own `ContentProvider`, and feed fresco with `content://` uri pointing to your provider.
In the ContentProvider, you provide the data stream from Firebase Storage using `fireStorage.getReference(path).getStream()`, and copy it down to file descriptor in `openFile` method. How to do that stream copying in `ContentProvider.openFile` is certainly answered on some other question.

Tested, and this way, Fresco cache works fine, and doesn't load again already cached images. It can work also offline, and doesn't need another database for remembering URLs.